# Do closed questions automatically get downvoted or not?

Tags: bug, status-completed, down-votes, closed-questions

In [April 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84978/should-questions-closed-as-not-a-real-question-and-off-topic-get-an-automati), closing a question for some reasons (then off-topic and not a real question) caused the Community user to downvote the question.

Officially, [this feature was removed in August 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190947/is-it-time-to-be-rid-of-automatic-down-votes-on-certain-closed-questions/190954#190954). Yet I still observe that closing a question as [off-topic, too broad or unclear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186073/which-new-close-reasons-carry-automatic-downvotes/186563#186563) instantly decreases a question's score by 1, and reopening increases the score by 1. I can't swear that this is systematic but I've definitely seen it happen many times.

[Here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/posts/19068/timeline)'s a recent example. The timeline shows that the question received two downvotes. But while it was closed as unclear, its score was -3, and since it was reopened its score is back at -2.

I'm tagging this [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) because the site behavior contradicts the [official documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190947/is-it-time-to-be-rid-of-automatic-down-votes-on-certain-closed-questions/190954#190954). I don't mean this as an opinion either way on whether automatic downvotes should or should not happen: just get the story straight, please.

Comment: Had a quick experiment on a per site meta - reopening a post cleared before the change reversed the -1 from community but reclosing it with *any* of the close options did not change the vote score subsequently.  Could be something sporadic though?

Comment: Through truth be told, I haven't seen this is Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let's Remove The Auto Downvote On Validated VLQ Flags (On Questions)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310974/lets-remove-the-auto-downvote-on-validated-vlq-flags-on-questions)

Comment: @gnat Uh? How would it be helpful to close a question “why does this effect happen?” as a duplicate of a thread that explains that the origin of this effect will not happen with newer posts? Better update the _answer_ here.

Comment: @Gilles I've been thinking about closing this as [can no longer be reproduced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231062/165773) but decided that it would be more convenient for readers to be explicitly referred to the post about when behavior has changed

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> **Note:  [the automatic downvote described below has been discontinued as of June 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310974/lets-remove-the-auto-downvote-on-validated-vlq-flags-on-questions).**

---

Closing a question [no longer directly triggers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190954/165773) an automatic down-vote on the question. *However*, closing a question can *indirectly* trigger a down-vote in one special circumstance: if there was an active Very Low Quality flag at the time the question was closed.

Although it's not particularly well-known, [Very Low Quality flags have carried with them an automatic downvote for about two years now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous/93606#93606). This extra downvote - attributed to [Community](/users/-1) - is cast *when the flag is marked helpful*...

...And closing a question with an active VLQ flag marks the flag "helpful". Hence, the down-vote you've observed coinciding with the question being closed.

When a post is re-opened, all Community downvotes are removed. [As Rory notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212871/do-closed-questions-automatically-get-downvoted-or-not#comment685190_212871), re-closing such a question won't re-apply the VLQ downvote (unless, of course, *another* VLQ flag is active at that time).

Comment: Hmmm. Sounds like two more reasons to get rid of VLQ on questions: it's obscure, and it's debatable — is [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/posts/19068/timeline) VLQ since the asker didn't put any effort into it, or is it not LVQ since it's perfectly answerable hence shouldn't be closed?

Comment: Eh; I kinda like this particular side-effect. For whatever reason, over half the folks flagging questions as VLQ *don't downvote* - as far as I'm concerned, this is a way of [extracting signal from folks too misguided to click the right button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111589/should-posts-flagged-low-quality-get-an-automatic-downvote-from-the-flagger/111591#111591). Regarding your example, it was VLQ because it was very poorly written; you edited it to improve that, at which point it wasn't anymore.