# What are the consequences for trying to upvote my own post couple of times?

Tags: support, voting, abuse

Out of boredom, I upvoted my own post few times in a row, getting the expected "You can't vote for your own post" message.

However, I wonder if there is any penalty for such behavior, e.g. automatic downvote instead?

I ask because after doing it, I suddenly got a downvote on that post. Was it the system or did someone put it there?

Comment: There's no system voting, other than as a side effect of user actions. If you get votes someone must have done something.

Comment: As a feature request this will do well :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Our systems detected this behavior and we have dispatched helicopters to your residence; please remain calm as our team comes to collect you.

Once you've arrived at our facility you'll be given free espresso, a trackball and working space in our secure vote storage warehouse. If you believe that this incident is the *result* of espresso, you'll be given chocolate milk instead.

Once all of this is out of your system, you'll be returned to your residence with most of your memory intact.

Please, wait where you are. We'll be right there.

Comment: Didn't we hate fun or are we on Iceland?

Comment: @rene _Fun_ is for the weak. We do serious business here. :P

Comment: Warning... I'm pretty sure this may cause people to attempt to upvote their own posts just to get a free coffee and helicopter ride.

Comment: Yeah, espresso and a chance to meet Tim's minions and maybe even Tim -- what's not to like?  Oh wait, that "most of your memory" part is a little concerning; it's no good if I meet Tim and then don't remember anything from it...

Comment: Oh... wait... maybe it already happened and I just don't remember.

Comment: *I keep throwing upvotes at my screen and nothing happens*... wait where did yesterday go?

Answer (score 14):

The system does not give automatic downvotes, except for [one very specific case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215328/152859).

If you click "upvote" on your own posts, nothing happens. You can't upvote your own posts.

If you upvoted on answers to a question you asked... don't do this out of boredom. You should vote (up or down) according the quality of the post.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Thanks for the edit - I didn't know that a VLQ flag on a question carried an automatic downvote if the flag was deemed helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't aware of that too until very recently, and to be honest still not 100% sure what are the conditions, e.g. if it "works" on answers to such question, only on answers with VLQ flag, etc. But it exists.

Comment: In short: vote for **content**, don't vote for **individuals**.