# Turn on the Mod Light for spam and other flags on beta sites

Tags: feature-request, spam, moderator-abilities

As a mod, I don't always click on the lovely `mod` button when I visit a site, and this sometimes allows spam to sit around longer than I would like.

On SO, Gaming, and other big sites, it isn't so much a problem because enough users will hit the `flag` button to get rid of it, but on many of the new, especially beta sites, spam may sit for a while before being flagged six times (we're already addressing the user training issue).

Please light up the *Mod Light* on beta sites!

[image: Bat Signal]

Answer (score 5):

I personally prefer that the mod indicator be kept only for mod flags. You can use greasemonkey to show the number of spam/offensive flags in the top bar as a separate indicator (posted originally [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36371/show-the-number-of-flags-beside-the-tools-link-for-10k-users/66724#66724)):

[image: Screenshot of the script in action]

[source code](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/87488), [direct install link](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/source/87488.user.js)

Comment: Can you clarify that you mean "Moderator Attention" flags?

Comment: @CRoss This just came up a few days ago too; when did "mod flags" ever stop meaning "moderator attention flags"? Spam/offensive flags have never been classified "mod flags"

Comment: I've never seen that defined anywhere, so I always assumed mod flags were all flags.  Others have as well.  If that's the way it is someone needs to write it down somewhere.  If it's written somewhere, please send me there and I'll shut up.

Comment: @CRoss I doubt that "mod flags are moderator attention flags" is specifically written somewhere, but that's what "mod flag" is short for; it'd be like documenting "rep is reputation". Spam/offensive flags are visible to non-moderators (10k users), and at one time they were visible to everyone on the site, so calling them "mod flags" would be a bit nonsensical

Comment: Regardless of the terminology, the fact is we've had really offensive comments and spam and stuff sit around because we're a smaller site and there's not a way for it to come to mod attention easily.  Maybe it isn't a "mod flag" but then how about built-in functionality to do what the greasemonkey hack does?

Answer (score 4):

It seems this has been [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), as far back as [2011 already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95267/295232).

Currently, most flags (including spam flags) count towards the 'number of pending flags' in the status bar, which is the closest thing to a mod button we have now. The only flags that don't count are close flags (those don't end up in the mod dashboard anyway) and Very Low Quality and Not An Answer flags cast in the last 15 minutes (or [1 hour on Stack Overflow and a few other large sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247658/295232)).