# Count of posts flagged for moderator attention does not agree

Tags: support, moderator-tools, navigation

Frequently I see that the number of items flagged in the navigation bar does not match what is reported on the moderation tools page.  Shouldn't these values match? or am I missing something in the calculation?

[image: nav bar versus tools flags display]

Answer (score 3):

The navigation bar counts the total number of flags including comment flags and spam/offensive flags.  It looks like these are not counted in the total on the tab in the moderation tools page.  I'm currently getting three different values reported, but they add up if I take everything into account.

[image: flag counts]

Comment: OK.  I get the 41, presumably 39 moderator + 2 comment -- since I wouldn't be able to see spam/offensive.  But I don't get the 37 (seems like it ought to be 39, 41, or 43 -- not 37).  In any event they ought to be the same, shouldn't they -- even for you. :-)

Comment: @tvanfosson: It would be less confusing to new moderators if the counts were consistent.  I started ignoring them a long time ago.  :)

Comment: I must have bit of OCD, though I can't tell since the psychiatrist's office has a misspelling in the street name and I can't force myself to go in since it appears to be at the wrong address.  ;-)