# As a moderator, am I supposed to handle NAA flags or let the reviewers do it?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation, not-an-answer

NAA flags have been [feeding into a review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228861/162102) for a while now.  I understood that post to mean that except in egregious cases we moderators should let the community handle it, just as we prefer that they handle closures and non-emergency deletions.  But I sometimes see other moderators take a more active hand with these flags and a search of MSE didn't turn up any authoritative guidance.  Each of the sites I'm a moderator on seems to do it a little differently.  Hence this question.

As a moderator, what should I do with a new NAA flag?  (I understand that I'll still need to handle ones with unclear review results or ones that didn't go to the queue at all, which should become apparent in a day or two.)  Or does it depend on the site somehow?

Comment: related: [Hide “not an answer” and “very low quality” flags in the moderator flag queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243145/165773)

Comment: I'll point out that if you let reviewers handle it, it can be undeleted. While this is useful for some answers which can be fixed and deserve to be undeleted (moreso for VLQ flags), some should never be undeleted. By doing it yourself when you see a flag, your diamond prevents that undeletion from occurring, and prevents users having to flag it *again* in the future, where a moderator *will* be required to handle it anyways.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that [these flags do not enter the moderator flag queue immediately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243145/hide-not-an-answer-and-very-low-quality-flags-in-the-moderator-flag-queue/247658#247658):

> This delay gives the community a chance to handle these flags first. If that doesn't happen, or if it *can't* happen, then it is made available to moderators for resolution. Keep in mind, not all posts can be processed via review, and when a post is processed through review but continues to garner flags the system reserves these for moderators. Therefore, **when you *do* see these flags in the mod queue, you should handle them** - it's unlikely anyone else will.

There's no real value to letting them sit around; either there's an immediate problem (and you'd be letting it fester) or there isn't (and you've no reason to leave the flag unresolved).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I see from there that it's a 15-minute delay, which on the smaller sites I tend to hang out on is too short for the community to review.  So I'd been ignoring the "raised 1 hour ago" NAAs, particularly in the cases where I can't tell but there might be merit (so let the community weigh in).  Are they out of the queue at that point and there's no benefit in that, then?

Comment: Whether they're out of the queue - or were ever even *in* the queue - is fairly irrelevant at that point; they're not being *handled*. 15 minutes is long enough for the queue to have picked them up and shown them to several reviewers, if reviewers are around; after that, consider them an exception to be handled.