# Don't show the weird half-generated flag bar during the grace period

Tags: feature-request, bug, flags, moderation, waffle-bar

So it turns out that NAA and VLQ flags have a 15-minute period during which the community is given a chance to handle them before mods do. When this happens, the flag does not show up in the flag queue but it is visible in the post timeline.

**The confusing part:** The flag-details bar still shows up at the bottom of the page, but contains no content — just a close button.  In the screenshot below I've increased its height significantly to make it clear:

[image: screenshot]

Could this be removed, or fixed to indicate what's happening so that no one else flips out like I just did?  (See [a prior revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/276984/3).)

Comment: An off-topic note: the user who commented there didn't flag the answer!

Comment: [Is the flag more than 15 minutes old?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243145/hide-not-an-answer-and-very-low-quality-flags-in-the-moderator-flag-queue/247658#247658)

Answer (score 6):

NAA flags take [a few minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243145/hide-not-an-answer-and-very-low-quality-flags-in-the-moderator-flag-queue/247658#247658) to enter the moderator queue. During this time, the issues bar (that grey thing) is in a weird flux state: it knows there are flags on the post, but it's not supposed to show them to you yet... so it just doesn't.

This should probably be fixed. Ideally, you'd be able to expand the little bar to show the flag (or it'd just show all the time). Alternatively, just don't show the bar until the flag is 'ready' for moderator attention.

In the meantime, you can deal with the flag by either deleting the answer or getting to the review task (through the timeline).

Comment: Thanks Undo and Gilles, that's definitely it.  I suppose this should morph into a `[feature-request]` then.

Comment: @MatthewRead I'd say it's still a bug. It's a thing that behaves wrongly, we want it to behave more rightly.

Comment: Tbh I don't see any real point in hiding the flag at all if you're viewing the post directly. The time limit was meant to not bother moderators looking at the flags queue, but if they're already looking at *the post* then it's useful to show them the flags on it, regardless of the time limit.