# What happens to NAA flag on a local meta?

Tags: support, flags, per-site-meta, not-an-answer

As far as I can tell, when an answer *on a main site* is flagged as "not an answer" it enters the low quality posts review queue.<sup>1</sup>

What happens on per-site metas? On meta sites the only review queues are suggested edits, close/reopen votes.

---

<sup>1</sup> According to [How do I properly use the “Not an Answer” flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185073): "The "not an answer" flag will trigger the answer to be reviewed by ordinary members of the site via the Low Quality Posts review queue if the answer has never been to that queue before."

Comment: Those go into the Mod queue. On main sites, at least on SO, NAA flags go into the mod-queue after an hour when they are not handled by the community by then.

Comment: After the comments here (and in chat) I was able to [find an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243145/hide-not-an-answer-and-very-low-quality-flags-in-the-moderator-flag-queue/247658#247658) mentioning that: "**Very Low Quality and Not An Answer flags do not enter the moderator queue for 15 minutes after they're raised.** This applies network-wide, except on Stack Overflow, Mathematics, TeX, Salesforce and Stack Overflow em Português (where the delay is a full hour) and meta sites (where they enter the queue immediately)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On meta those flags go straight to moderators.  On main sites they go to the queue first but eventually go to moderators if the community doesn't handle them.  On most sites "eventually" means after 15 minutes and on a few it means after an hour.  Even if meta sites had this review queue and even if the higher limit were used, my guess is that most of those flags would go to moderators anyway -- most people don't check meta nearly as frequently as they check main *and* meta has a smaller active population to begin with.  Further, in my experience as a mod on several sites, flags on meta are much more rare than flags on main.  Putting all that together, it's really not worth creating (and encouraging use of) another review queue on per-site metas for these relatively-rare flags.

It might be a good idea to find a place (maybe in the mod-specific help? maybe in the flag UI?) to remind moderators that they shouldn't expect the community to handle these flags on meta.  On some of my sites, mods pretty much ignore new NAA flags to encourage the community to handle things directly.  There's no point in doing that on meta; the community can't handle them.