# Have Tools link default to Tools

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, 10k-tools, review

The new behavior for the `tools` link in the menu bar, is to bring up the `review` page, with a choice on the upper left of `Tools/Review`.  While I like being able to get to both from that link, I'd much rather it defaulted to `Tools` instead of `Review`, since that's why I clicked on the link.

**EDIT:**  While it's great that the setting is `sticky` and will stay where you last set it, there is  one problem with that.  If I go to edit a suggested edit from the black box on the top menu bar, the next time I hit `tools` it goes back to the Review->Suggested Edits.

Comment: It *is* "sticky" in the sense that it remembers your last selection. But I didn't pay enough attention the first time that I clicked it to see that "review" is the default.

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know it's `sticky`.

Comment: perhaps the "suggested edits" number, which I find a bit annoying, could be replaced with a "review" link.

Comment: @Nick: I'm all for it, but I'm not sure this is going to happen. The reason the change Lance is talking about here exists at all is because of [something that slhck and I started yesterday](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102457/). Waffles was good enough to try and accommodate our concerns, despite Jeff's pig-headed stubbornness with nary an attempt at justification. For whatever reason, he'll refuse any request to include any additional information in the top bar, no matter how useful or how much it might improve the site.

Comment: I like the "suggested edits" number, because it alerts me that there are some, and it's small and unobtrusive.  Everytime I see it, I click on it and go take care of business.

Comment: @Cody: thanks, I didn't see that question.

Comment: I can pull the suggested edit list out of /review ... would that solve this?

Comment: @waffles, hmmm, that sounds like it would work.  I was thinking more of a setting I could choose that would always let me go to the same place, but that would probably work just fine.  To be honest, it'd be less of a deal if [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36371/show-the-number-of-flags-beside-the-tools-link-for-10k-users) was implemented, since I mainly hit the tools to check if there are flags.

Comment: @lance let me know if my answer works for you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just corrected the ways we "sticky" the tabs.

We now only "sticky" the tab in tools or review if it is selected explicitly by **clicking on the tab**. Same goes for the "review vs. tools" selection.

This means if you click on the "bat" signal which sends you to flags, nothing is made sticky. If you click on the "bat" signal sending you to suggested edits, nothing is made sticky.

This is controlled by the "s=1" portion of the query string.

Comment: to be deployed later

Comment: thanks, that's a great way to implement that.

Comment: @waffles: Will the "tools" bring you to Tools the very first time you click it after reaching 10k? (This was originally requested, if I didn't get it wrong, and it makes sense in my opinion.)

Answer (score 8):

I agree with this. It's not obvious that this is a feature, not a bug: the new change threw me and others for a loop that we mistakenly filed bug reports about it.

Clicking on the word tools should bring you to the Tools page, not some other page. It's nice that it's available, but links should never "lie" about where they're going, and it should be obvious how to get to one or the other page:

[image: Huh?]

Comment: we could rename tools to "review" on the header if review is selected ... but that may lead to more confusion.

Comment: @waffles I'm not sure what was wrong with the original functionality: if you have access to tools, you get tools. If you don't get review. Tools and review aren't different "views" of the same data set: they have different functionalities, and the toggle metaphor seems misplaced. But if it's going to stay a toggle, the toggle needs to be made a lot clearer. In Sketchy and Programmers, it's just two words next to each other with no indication that it's a switch.

Comment: I will fix the css in any sites it is confusing agree with you there ... Jeff feels strongly about not adding any more links in the top. I can not win that battle

Comment: @waffles I liked the old functionality, before review was in the header 100% of the time :/, but I can live with a CSS change combined with the change you made for this question. Thanks.

Comment: just checked in a fix for that ... should be there in the next few hours

Comment: @waffles - I needed this question to figure out how to use it.  It never occurred to me once that a grayed-out tab is clickable.  That's a pretty common UI color choice for 'disabled'.